# how to clear animation in javascript when restart button is pressed before current one is finished?

Tags: javascript

Running the animation at https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_animate_3 shows nice animation where a block moves down the diagonal of a square.

But I noticed if I press the button very quickly before the block reaches the bottom, it starts new one while the first one is still moving. leading to very jagged motion, like this

[image]

You have to press the button quickly to see this. I think this happens because the javascript code posted there does not correctly initializes the animation each time?

What code changes is need to fix this? I am posting the code here also in case.

To be clear. I want when the button is pressed to immediately clear the current running animation and start new one with the block at the stop left corner.  Not wait for the current one to finish.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>

<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p> 

<div id ="container">
  <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>

<script>
function myMove() {
  let id = null;
  const elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  let pos = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you probably just need to move the id variable from setInterval outside the mymove function, so each time the button is clicked the previous animations interval is cancelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a global `id`. This way, when the button is clicked and the `myMove` function is called, it will **cancel the currently running animation** by calling `clearInterval(id)`, and then start a new animation. Something like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  #container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
  }
  
  #animate {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="animate"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    let id = null; // Moved the id outside

    function myMove() {
      const elem = document.getElementById("animate");
      let pos = 0;
      clearInterval(id);
      id = setInterval(frame, 5);

      function frame() {
        if (pos == 350) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          pos++;
          elem.style.top = pos + "px";
          elem.style.left = pos + "px";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code. But it does start a NEW animation while the first is running. It waits until the first one is finished, then new one is started. I wanted the button to start new one right away, canceling the one currently running. That is the whole point of my question. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.  Notice that when you click the button now when your animation is running, it keeps running. This is not what I wanted.

Comment: Yes! That is the main point of my question. so pressing the button acts as if it started fresh each time. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. Yes, this is how it should work. THanks